# Images overlapping in floated divs

Tags: html, css, overlap

I've created a very basic HTML template for a friends eBay listings, and I'm having issues with the images in the left column overlapping the text in the right column when viewed on smaller devices. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Example of image overlapping]

Here's my code, I've replaced the images as they were TinyURLs (be warned, it's probably not great):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Custom Shadez</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0 auto; max-width:900px;">

 <div>
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Custom Shadez logo" width="100%">
    </div>
    
     <h1 style="text-align:center; font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">LOCS Sunglasses - Flattop Wayfarer Style Frames</h1> 
        
     <h2 style="text-align:center; font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Excellent Quality - FREE Postage Australia Wide</h2>
        
    <div style="width:50%; max-width:550px; float:left">
    
<!------------------------------------------EDIT PHOTO IMAGES AND POSTAGE LOGO HERE-------------------------------------------->

     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="photo of sunglasses" width="100%">   
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="free postage" width="100%" style="margin-top:50px">
    </div>
    
    <div style="width:46%; float:right; margin-top:-24px;">
    
<!------------------------------------------EDIT VIEW MORE LINKS HERE-------------------------------------------->

    
     <p style="font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px"><a href="http://stores.ebay.com.au/CustomShadez/Polarised-/_i.html?_fsub=2608818011" target="_blank"><strong>> VIEW OTHER POLARISED SUNGLASSES</strong></a></p>
        
        <p style="font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px"><a href="http://stores.ebay.com.au/CustomShadez" target="_blank"><strong>> VIEW FULL SUNGLASSES RANGE</strong></a></p>
        
        
<!------------------------------------------ITEM DESCRIPTION-------------------------------------------->
        
    <div style="margin-top:7px">
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="free postage and handling" width="100%">
    </div>
    
     <div style="margin-top:7px">
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="item description" width="100%">
    </div>
    
    <div >
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="dimensions of sunglasses" width="80%">
    </div>
    
    <p style="font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; margin-top:-7px"> 
 <strong>Size (mm):</strong> (A) 148 (B) 58 (C) 45 (D) 138<br>
 <strong>Style:</strong> Flat Top Wayfarer<br>
 <strong>Lens:</strong> Grey / Category 3<br>
 <strong>Frame:</strong> Gloss Black<br>
 <strong>Features:</strong> UV 400 Protection
    </p>
    
     <div style="margin-top:7px">
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="postage" width="100%">
    </div>
    
    <p style="font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px"> 
    <strong>AUSTRALIA</strong> (Registered + Tracking) = FREE<br>
 <strong>AUSTRALIA</strong> (Express Post)  = $8.45<br>
 <strong>USA / Canada, Asia & NZ</strong> = $9.95 (AUD)<br>
 <strong>UK & Europe</strong> = $14.95 (AUD)
    </p>
    
    <p style="font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px"> 
    Items are sent within 1 working day of receiving payment. All postage costs are capped so you can purchase as many pair as you like at no extra postage cost
    </p>
    
    <div style="margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="postage services" width="100%">
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-top:10px">
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="payment" width="100%">
    </div>
    
      <p style="font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px"> 
  Preferred payment method is PayPal or Bank Deposit Feel free to contact us with any enquiries regarding payment.
    </p>
    
    <div style="margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="payment" width="100%">
    </div>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? I've done quite a bit of research and can't seem to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what code you've written, but give this a try:

img { display:block; width: 100% !important; } in your css file.